# How to set @EnvironmentObject in an existing Storyboard based project?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have an iOS project built with **Storyboard** and **UIKit**. Now I want to develop the new screens using **SwiftUI**. I added a Hosting View Controller to the existing **Storyboard** and used it to show my newly created **SwiftUI** view.

But I couldn't figure out how to create an **@EnvironmenetObject** that can be used anywhere throughout the application. I should be able to access/set it in any of my UIKit based ViewController as well as my **SwiftUI** views.

Is this possible? If so how to do it? In a pure **SwiftUI** app, we set the environment object like below,

```
@main
struct myApp: App {
    @StateObject var item = Item()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(item)
        }
    }
}
```

But in my case, there is no function like this since it is an existing iOS project with **AppDelegate** and **SceneDelegate**. And the initial view controller is marked in Storyboard.
How to set this and access the object anywhere in the app?

Comment: I don't believe you can use the environment property modifier directly in uikit. You could pass the same object reference tomyournuikit views and inject it into the environment of your SwiftUI view

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am not able to set the @EnvironmentObject itself since I couldn't figure out how to set it to my first SwiftUI View. The point to note here is SwiftUI view is not my root view.

Comment: Somewhere you create your SwiftUI view, probably in `UIHostingController`. Just append the `.environmentObject` to the view you specify as the `rootView`

Comment: I did like you said but getting error `'self' used in property access 'order' before 'super.init' call`. Please find the code [here](https://gist.github.com/yaalisri/b70e79b283df9ca04512654c17a097c0).

Comment: [edit] your question to show your code

Comment: You can't use `@StateObject`. You would probably want to get the object you are going to inject into the environment from somewhere else (such as the app delegate)

Comment: Pls find my updated [code](https://gist.github.com/yaalisri/b70e79b283df9ca04512654c17a097c0). App is getting crashed saying `Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<eStore.ItemDetailView, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<eStore.Item>>>' (0x7fff87402680) to 'eStore.ItemDetailView' (0x10c9d2020).` Also getting a warning.

Comment: Include your code in your question.

Comment: Do not force cast your view. and try wrapping the view with the modifier in a AnyView

Comment: @Aswath Got it. It works now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .environmentObject modifier changes the type of the view from ItemDetailView to something else. Force casting it will cause an error. Instead, try wrapping it into an AnyView.

```
class OrderObservable: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var order: String = "Hello"
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var orderObservable: OrderObservable
    
    var body: some View {
        
        EmptyView()
            .onAppear(perform: {
                print(orderObservable.order)
            })
    }
}

class ItemDetailViewHostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder,rootView: AnyView(ItemDetailView().environmentObject(OrderObservable())))
    }
}
```

This works for me. Is this what you require?

**EDIT**:
Ok, so I gave the setting the property from a ViewController all through the View. It wasn't as easy as using a property wrapper or a view modifier, but it works. I gave it a spin. Please let me know if this satisfies your requirement. Also, I had to get rid of the HostingController subclass.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var orderObservable = OrderObservable()
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let myVC = (segue.destination as? MyViewController) else { return }
        myVC.orderObservable = orderObservable
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var orderObservable: OrderObservable!
    var anycancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @IBAction @objc func buttonSegueToHostingVC() {
        let detailView = ItemDetailView().environmentObject(orderObservable)
        present(UIHostingController(rootView: detailView), animated: true)
        
        orderObservable.$order.sink { newVal in
            print(newVal)
        }
        .store(in: &anycancellables)
    }
}


class OrderObservable: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var order: String = "Hello"
    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
            self.order = "World"
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var orderObservable: OrderObservable
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("\(orderObservable.order)")
    }
}
```

Basically I'm creating the observable object in the ViewController class, passing it to the MyViewController class and finally create a hosting controller with the ItemDetailView and setting it's environmentObject and presenting it.

Comment: This works for me! Thanks. But part of the question is how do I set the value of this @EnvironmentObject in my ViewController class before I show this new View created with SwiftUI?

Comment: Also i am getting warning `Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.` when is set the rootView inside init method.

Comment: Hmm, can't you directly set the view controller's property?

Comment: Okay, this works. But orderObservable value is accessible only in ItemDetailView. If I create one more SwiftUI View and try to navigate to it from ItemDetailView, then access the same orderObservable, it crashes saying it's nil. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Are you creating the new view and injecting the environment object into the next SwiftUI view too? SiwftUI doesn't automatically do that for you.

Eg: NavigationLink { NextView().environmentObject(orderObservable) }

I can't see the code, so I'm basing the answer on my guess of what you might have done incorrectly, can you update the question with the exact code, so that I'm sure.

Comment: Exactly this is what I was doing wrong. I just started with SwiftUI, so the mistake. Can you also help me on how to access this again in my View Controller? For example, if I set the orderObservable to new value in one of my SwiftUI Views, how do I update it in my old View Controller?

Comment: if you mean, you want to update one of the values INSIDE the observable, like the order string, you can just update it in the view struct itself, since OrderObservable is a class and passed as a reference. But if you want to change the observable itself with a new object, then there are a couple of options. like using a Binding

Comment: Yeah, I am updating one of the values of the class in my current SwiftUI View. But how do I get that value back in my UIKit ViewController?

Comment: I can help you, but you need to get some basics of Combine down if you really want to understand what is going on and want to work with some complex use cases. See my updated answer. And if my answer satisfies you, it'd be great, if you mark it as correct :)

Comment: Thanks! This works! I will read about combine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230659/discussion-between-aswath-and-yaali).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on tackling this problem. My app targets iOS 14 or above:

## The current state

I have a Main.storyboard file with one view controller scene set as the initial view controller with custom class `ViewController`. Here's the custom class implementation:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
}
```

## The goal

To use this class in a SwiftUI app life cycle and make it react and interact to `@EnvironmentObject` instance (In this case let's call it a theme manager).

## Solution

I will define a `ThemeManager` observable object with a `Theme` published property like so:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class ThemeManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var theme = Theme.purple
}

struct Theme {
    let labelColor: Color
}

extension Theme {
    static let purple = Theme(labelColor: .purple)
    static let green = Theme(labelColor: .green)
}

extension Theme: Equatable {}
```

Next, I created a `ViewControllerRepresentation` to be able to use the `ViewController` in SwiftUI:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ViewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var themeManager: ThemeManager

    // Use this function to pass the @EnvironmentObject to the view controller 
    // so that you can change its properties from inside the view controller scope.
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController { coder in
            ViewController(themeManager: themeManager, coder: coder)
        }
        return viewController!
    }

    // Use this function to update the view controller when the @EnvironmentObject changes.
    // In this case I modify the label color based on the themeManager.
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.label.textColor = UIColor(themeManager.theme.labelColor)
    }
}
```

I then updated `ViewController` to accept a `themeManager` instance:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    let themeManager: ThemeManager

    init?(themeManager: ThemeManager, coder: NSCoder) {
        self.themeManager = themeManager
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @IBAction func toggleTheme(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if themeManager.theme == .purple {
            themeManager.theme = .green
        } else {
            themeManager.theme = .purple
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the last thing to do is create an instance of the theme manager and pass it as an environment object to the view controller representation:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ThemeEnvironmentApp: App {
    @StateObject private var themeManager = ThemeManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ViewControllerRepresentation()
                .environmentObject(themeManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Running the app shows our view controller with a label and a button. Tapping the button triggers the `IBAction`, which changes the `themeManager.theme`, which triggers a call to the representation's `updateUIViewController(_:, context:)`:

[image: demo of the solution]